# R: Handling tags in R rpart

Tags: r, decision-trees

I'm new to regression trees and wanted some advice. 
I'm working on a data set in which a few of the columns contains tag-like information (basically tags separated by commas). 
My goal is to create a regression tree using the `rpart` function in R and but I don't know how to handle those columns. 
Tidyr offers a useful function `seperate_rows` which would allow me to split the tags into multiple rows, each with one "tag". However, this makes my data set go from roughly 10k entries to over 3 million and I'm concerned it might affect my results.

Comment: Depending on what the tags represent and if they are part of your features or are the values you're trying to predict, you could try converting them into 0/1 columns indicating if an observation had a certain tag.

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to mention that the tags are used to predict some other value (not tag like), but good idea, I'll give it a try!